# gzip .js files with ?ver in .htaccess

Tags: javascript, compression, version, gzip

I have enabled compression in .htaccess

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
```

But I am still getting a lot of uncompressed JavaScript files with version numbers appended to the URI (?ver). Example:

```
/js/slides.min.jquery.js?ver=3.3.1
```

Any way to effectively compress these files too?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to also add `application/javascript`and `application/x-javascript` content-type

Comment: glad to help you. if you don't know why a file is not compressed, just check its `content-type` via firebug (under `net` panel) and thus add that value in your list